# GridView with tempelate TextFields

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio, gridview

i have a grid view with textfields as tempelates.
i have connected it to a DB so 'm able to perform Insert operation when entred in a textfield for the checked column. now i have to update the DB so i want to display what is present in the DB and 'm only able get the 1st Column that is the Customer_Name the rest will be empty so how do i do it??

this is what i have been tring

```
                SqlCommand search2 = new SqlCommand("select * from OtherCostData", con);


                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(search2);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

[image: GridView that i have]
i'm not able to put my gridview aspx code its giving me some indentation error however i try to format it

Comment: post the gridview aspx portion

Comment: @syedmohsin bro i'm not able to post it because its giving me some indentation problem